# ¿Por qué no funciona este servidor hecho con socket.io y php?

Tags: php, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy intentando hacer un juego multijugador de estrategia de conseguir hierro para construir y uranio para atacar. Llevo este código hecho hasta ahora:

Backend:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

/*
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
*/
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000);
console.log("Server started.");

i1=0
obj={}
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   i1++
   obj[i1]={name:"",iron:0,uranium:0,drillers:0,trucks:0,nukes:0}
   socket.on("name",(e)=>{
      obj[i1].name=e.data
   })
   setInterval(()=>{
      for(i in obj){
         socket.emit("msg",{
         name:obj[i].name,
         user:i,iron:obj[i].iron,
         uranium:obj[i].uranium,
         drillers:obj[i].drillers,
         trucks:obj[i].trucks,
         nukes:obj[i].nukes
     })
      }
   },1000)
})
```

Frontend (login):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<title>74nk5</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">This is a game made by an anonymous person. Hope you enjoy!</a>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214396"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214396" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214398"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214398" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214399"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214399" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214409"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214409" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275187"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275187" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275188"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275188" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">↓↓↓ Your name below ↓↓↓</a>
</nav>
<form method="POST"action="panel">
  <div class="form-group">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is the tale of:</small>
    <input name="name" type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter the name here">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Frontend (sala principal):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<title>74nk5</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Yeah, you logged in!!! Please, press F12 to play.</a>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214396"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214396" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214398"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214398" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214399"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214399" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214409"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214409" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275187"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275187" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275188"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275188" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
</nav>
<script>
init=()=>{
  obj={}
  socket=io("https://drwerenverlivitz.herokuapp.com/")
  //Set the username.
  socket.emit("name",{data:<? echo $_POST["name"]; ?>})
  //Store all users with their variables.
  socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
    obj[e.user]={name:e.name,iron:e.iron,uranium:e.uranium,trucks:e.trucks,drillers:e.drillers,nukes:e.nukes}
  })
  render()
}
render=()=>{
  //Show all users with their variables.
  console.table(obj)
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
setTimeout(init,1)
</script>
```

El caso es que iba muy bien con este código, pero al hacer un `echo $_POST["name"]` no me imprime la variable guardada en el código PHP, esto es muy raro, no se si bootstrap estará bloqueando la impresión de código, el caso es que me funciona en un archivo vacío, solo con el formulario y el `echo $_POST["name"]` pero de otra forma no. ¿Hay alguna solución? Gracias por la ayuda de todos modos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Se solucionó. Dejo el enlace del frontend corregido:

Frontend (login):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<title>74nk5</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">This is a game made by an anonymous person. Hope you enjoy!</a>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214396"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214396" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214398"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214398" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214399"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214399" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214409"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214409" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275187"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275187" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275188"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275188" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">↓↓↓ Your name below ↓↓↓</a>
</nav>
<form method="POST"action="panel/">
  <div class="form-group">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is the tale of:</small>
    <input name="name" type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter the name here">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Frontend (sala principal):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<title>74nk5</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Yeah, you logged in!!! Please, press F12 and tipe 'console' to play.</a>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214396"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214396" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214398"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214398" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_214399"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214399" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_214409"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214409" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275187"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275187" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275188"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275188" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275189"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275189" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275190"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275190" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275191"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275191" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275192"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275192" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275193"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275193" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275194"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275194" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275195"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275195" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275196"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275196" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275197"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275197" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275198"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275198" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275199"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275199" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275200"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275200" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275201"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275201" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275202"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275202" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275203"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275203" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275204"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275204" async></script></div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div id="linkslot_275205"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275205" async></script></div>
  <div id="linkslot_275206"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=275206" async></script></div>
</nav>
<script>
init=()=>{
  obj={}
  socket=io("https://drwerenverlivitz.herokuapp.com/")
  //Set the username.
  socket.emit("name",{data:"<? echo $_POST["name"]; ?>"})
  //Store all users with their variables.
  socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
    obj[e.user]={name:e.name,iron:e.iron,uranium:e.uranium,trucks:e.trucks,drillers:e.drillers,nukes:e.nukes,teslatowers:e.teslatowers}
  })
  render()
}
render=()=>{
  //Show all users with their variables.
  console.table(obj)
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
setTimeout(init,1)
</script>
```